# RabbitMQ Consumer Polling Configuration

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a spring boot application that consumes from one queue in RabbitMQ and multiple applications that send messages to this queue. My issue here is that the publishing rate is higher than the consuming rate causing the consumer application CPU usage to spike. I was wondering if there is a way to configure the polling rate from rabbitMQ queue to consumer. I want to be able to configure how many messages per second consumer is polling. Bellow, I have added the consumer spring cloud config in the yml file for reference. Any help will be appreciated it. thanks

in application.yml

```
spring:
 cloud:
  bindings:
   consumerApplication:
    group: consumerApplicationGroup
    durableSubscription: true
    consumer:
     concurrecy: 1
```